# Запись строк из файла в массив

Tags: c, массивы

Есть файл: в нём записаны некоторые строки.

```
Password: "A$%&_'+)*`
Note: ~!@#$%^&*()_+
Password: rxf 
Note: qwe 
Password: rxfsuz 
Note: йцукен 
Password: кчф 
Note: йцу 
Password: хьбг79х5г7хь5г75 
Note: фывфыв
```

Задача в том, чтобы считать пароли в один массив, а заметки - в другой.

Проблема в том, что я не могу корректно считать строку в массив.
На c-cpp.ru прочёл про массивы строк: это 
char[кол-во строк][длинна строк]
Окей. Я объявил такой массив. Два массива.
Начинаю построчно, в while(true), читать файл. Вот так:
dataPointer = fgets(dataFromFile, 2048, file);
Это должно считать в переменную максимум 2047 символов из текущей строки файла, верно?
Для того, чтобы строки писались в массивы поочерёдно, я сделал так:

```
int i=0, j=0;
if (i=j){
    fgets(stMass[i], 2048, dataPointer);
    i++;
} else {
    fgets(ndMass[i], 2048, dataPointer);
    j++
}
```

Вот только не записывает строку в массив, выкидывает эксепшн нарушения прав чтения из памяти.
Сразу скажу, я студент-первокурсник, у которого на учёбе основной язык - VB6, а C идёт отдельным предметом, но не объясняется вообще, а сдавать надо. До сих пор удавалось самому находить ответы на вопросы, но сейчас - затык. 
Собственно, вопрос: как правильно считать строку в массив? Возможно, в fgets надо писать не указатель, а dataFromFile, который указан в fgets, на который этот указатель ссылается? Но так тоже не работает. Читал про разыменовывание указателей (* перед именем), но так тоже не работает, видимо, я не понимаю механизма работы оного.

Код таков:

```
void decrypt(){
HANDLE currConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
FILE *encryptedPasswords;
char dataFromFile[2048], *dataFromFilePointer, pwdFromFile[64][1024], noteFromFile[64][1024];
int i = 0, j = 0;
char cuttedStr[1024];
printf("Opening file with encrypted passwords...");
encryptedPasswords = fopen("encrypted passwords.txt", "r");
if (NULL == encryptedPasswords) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | LightRed);
    printf("\n[ERR]");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | White);
    printf("Passwords file not found or can not be read\n");
    Sleep(500);
    printf("Exiting into main menu...");
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
else {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | Green);
    printf("OK\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | White);
    while (true) {
        dataFromFilePointer = fgets(dataFromFile, sizeof(dataFromFile), encryptedPasswords);
        if (NULL == dataFromFilePointer) {
            if (feof(encryptedPasswords) != 0) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | LightRed);
                printf("\n[ERR]");
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(currConsole, Black << 4 | White);
                printf("Can't read from file\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] = "\n") {
            dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if (i == j){
            sprintf(pwdFromFile[i], "%s", strncpy(cuttedStr, dataFromFilePointer + 10,sizeof(cuttedStr)));
            i++;
        }
        else {
            sprintf(noteFromFile[i], "%s", strncpy(cuttedStr, dataFromFilePointer + 6, sizeof(cuttedStr)));
            j++;
        }
    }
}
    printf("%s \n", pwdFromFile[0]);
    printf("%s \n", noteFromFile[0]);
    printf("%s \n", pwdFromFile[1]);
    printf("%s \n", noteFromFile[1]);
    printf("%s \n", pwdFromFile[2]);
    printf("%s \n", noteFromFile[2]);
    printf("%s \n", pwdFromFile[3]);
    printf("%s \n", noteFromFile[3]);
    printf("%s \n", pwdFromFile[4]);
    printf("%s \n", noteFromFile[4]);
Sleep(5000000);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPD: Обновил ответ в соответствии с вопросом

Пройдемся по Вашему коду.

1) Функция `decrypt()` объявлена как `void`, но возвращает `0`, если не удалось открыть файл. Поменяем тип функции на `int`.

```
int decrypt() {
```

2) Названия `i` и `j` для переменных не очень подходящие назовем их...

```
int pwd_counter  = 0,
    note_counter = 0;
```

**3)** Строка `if (dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] = "\n") {`. Вы, видимо, хотите заменить перевод строки на нулевой символ. Нужно заменить **присваивание** `=` на **сравнение** `==` и **строку** `"\n"` на **символ** `'\n'` (обратите внимание на кавычки).

```
if (dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] == '\n')
```

4) Условие `if (i == j){` не много сбивает столку. Почему бы просто не проверить, является ли первый символ строки буквой `P`:

```
if (*dataFromFilePointer == 'P') {
```

5) Почему бы не сделать вывод строк циклом?

```
for (int i = 0; i < pwd_counter; ++i)
    printf("%s \n%s \n", pwdFromFile[i], noteFromFile[i]);
```

6) Мы должны закрыть файл и освободить переменную `dataFromFilePointer`

```
free(dataFromFilePointer);
fclose(encryptedPasswords);
```

Итого:

```
int decrypt() {
    HANDLE  currConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    FILE*   encryptedPasswords;
    char    dataFromFile[2048],
            pwdFromFile[64][1024], 
            noteFromFile[64][1024], 
            cuttedStr[1024];
    char*   dataFromFilePointer;
    int     pwd_counter  = 0,
            note_counter = 0;

    printf("Opening file with encrypted passwords...");

    encryptedPasswords = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == encryptedPasswords) {
        printf("\n[ERR]");
        printf("Passwords file not found or can not be read\n");
        printf("Exiting into main menu...");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("OK\n");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        dataFromFilePointer = fgets(dataFromFile, sizeof(dataFromFile), encryptedPasswords);

        if (dataFromFilePointer == NULL) {
            if (feof(encryptedPasswords) != 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                printf("\n[ERR]");
                printf("Can't read from file\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] == '\n')
            dataFromFilePointer[strlen(dataFromFilePointer) - 1] = '\0';

        if (*dataFromFilePointer == 'P') {
            sprintf(pwdFromFile[pwd_counter], "%s", strncpy(cuttedStr, dataFromFilePointer + 10, sizeof(cuttedStr)));
            pwd_counter++;
        } else {
            sprintf(noteFromFile[note_counter], "%s", strncpy(cuttedStr, dataFromFilePointer + 6, sizeof(cuttedStr)));
            note_counter++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pwd_counter; ++i)
        printf("%s \n%s \n", pwdFromFile[i], noteFromFile[i]);

    free(dataFromFilePointer);
    fclose(encryptedPasswords);
}
```

Убрал все `sleep` и изменения цвета консоли, т.к. мой редактор это не поддерживает. Конечно, и сам подход не очень хорош, но теперь код должен работать исправно.

Comment: Ох, спасибо за ответ. На самом деле, почти всё из этого у меня уже было написано (но местами немного по-другому), и фаткически работать оно стало после изменения одной-единственной строки.

Вместо fgets - sprintf. Вот так оно стало сохранять в массив. Пока единственна проблема - во втором массиве, почему-то, первый элемент забивает все символы перед строкой большими буквами М. А в остальных строках такого нет. Странно.

Comment: @Пшеница, да не за что. Если Вы нашли решение, то оформите его как ответ и примите как верный.

Comment: @Пшеница, напишите подробнее, что именно Вам нужно, а также выложите содержимое считываемого файла.

Comment: Считать файл в два массива. В одном - "зашифрованные" пароли, во втором - примечания. Задание такое: шифровать введённый пароль, записывать в файлик, и чтобы потом можно было расшифровать там же. 
И на данный момент работает почти всё: программа считывает строки в массивы, в верном порядке, но первая строка второго массива выглядит как 

MMMMMMMMMMMMMMNote: ~!@#$%^&*()_+

А со всеми остальными нормально. В файле это:

Password: "A$%&_'+)*`,
Note: ~!@#$%^&*()_+
Password: rxf
Note: qwe
Password: rxfsuz
Note: йцукен
Password: кчф
Note: йцу
Password: хьбг79х5г7хь5г75
Note: фывфыв

Comment: @Пшеница, нужно считывать строки вместе со словами "Password:" и "Note"?

Comment: Да, вместе с ними, чтобы было видно, где что. Хотя, наверное, можно попробовать обойтись и без них... Это идея, да. Слова те можно и отдельно напечатать на экран будет. Сейчас попробую.) 

Попробовал. Кажется, дело не в строке, а в массиве. После обрезания выводит MMMMMMMMMMM~!@#$%^&*()_+. Т.е. Note: обрезалось, а "мусор" остался... Странно. Массивы объявлены совершенно одинаково, заполняются одинаково, но в первом такого нет, во втором есть.

Comment: @Пшеница, выложите код в вопрос (там есть кнопочка _править_).